# How do i match regular expression pattern in redis

Tags: redis

I have 3 keys id=foo1, id=foo10. id=foo100.
I would like to match only keys which ends with id=foo1 or contains id=foo1

So the first query should return a single result and the last query should return 3 results.

Comment: As I mentioned before in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16169583/how-to-match-the-exact-string-with-multiple-url-using-regex/16169628#16169628), `id=foo1([^\d]|$)` should suffice.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991777/ruby-regex-key-search

Comment: Are you asking about querying those keys from redis? ( based on how you tagged the question ) If so you may want to clarify the question a little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like

```
r=Redis.new
r.keys("*foo1")
r.keys("*foo1*")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
keys = ["id=foo1","id=foo10","id=foo100"]
p keys.select {|x| x.include? 'id=foo1'}
#=> ["id=foo1", "id=foo10", "id=foo100"]
p keys.select {|x| x.end_with? 'id=foo1'}
#=> ["id=foo1"]
```